# Python Selenium - opening Edge with default user profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

i'm using this code to open edge with the defaut profile settings:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True    
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PopA2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Default")   
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\\Users\\PopA2\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64 (1)\\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "C:\\Users\\PopA2\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64 (1)\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

but i am getting this error:

> PS C:\Users\PopA2> & "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe"
> "c:/Users/PopA2/OneDrive/Desktop/test de pe net.py" Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "c:/Users/PopA2/OneDrive
> Group/Desktop/test de pe net.py", line 13, in 
> driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "C:\Users\PopA2\Downloads\edgedriver_win64 (1)\msedgedriver.exe")
> File "C:\Program
> Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\msedge\selenium_tools\webdriver.py",
> line 108, in **init**
> desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 157, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 252, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> MSEdge failed to start: was killed.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> msedge location C:\Users\PopA2\Downloads\edgedriver_win64
> (1)\msedgedriver.exe is no longer running, so MSEdgeDriver is
> assuming that MSEdge has crashed.)

Comment: I've seen this issue before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770506/webdriverexception-unknown-error-msedge-failed-to-start-was-killed.
And this was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69848796

Comment: How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709117/python-selenium-opening-edge-with-default-user-profile/70738711#70738711) helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. You need to remove the *`Default`* sub-directory from the *path* mentioned through `user-data-dir`.

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PopA2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
```

Comment: it does not work, i still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the program under LocalSystem account? If so, the issue is the same as which mentioned in the comment and [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/635817/msedgedriver-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesn39t-exis.html).

I suggest that you can provide feedback about this issue to Edge team by pressing Alt+Shift+I in Edge. For now, the only workaround is not to run Edge under LocalSystem account.

Besides, if you want to run Edge with default profile, you can use the below line of code and there's no need to specify `profile-directory`. You can also add `--remote-debugging-port` argument to fix the issue:

```
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PopA2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```